# Google Visualization: draw vertical line in annotation chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have managed to display data successfully using an [annotation chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart).

However I want to be able to draw several vertical lines to correlate the displayed data with events that happened independently at several points in time. I want to display these events as vertical lines with text labels in them, like this:

[image]

Any attempts to do so by using the annotation role and additional rows of data have been unsuccessful ([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yhg4ypLd/7/)):

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});
    data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotationText'});

data.addRows([
      [new Date(2314, 2, 15), 12400, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2314, 2, 16), 24045, 'Lalibertines', 'First encounter'],
      [new Date(2314, 2, 17), 35022, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2314, 2, 18), 12284, 'Lalibertines', 'Attack on our crew!'],
      [new Date(2314, 2, 20), 8476, undefined, undefined],
      [new Date(2314, 2, 21), 0, 'Lalibertines', 'All crew lost']
]);
```

Is this even possible? If not, can anyone recommend any other possibilities?

Thanks.

Comment: don't think you'll get there with `AnnotationChart` -- but very possible with `ComboChart` --> [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38016496/5090771) -- use option `annotations:{style:'line'}` to get labels beside vertical lines...