# Add custom point in Google Charts

Tags: graph, charts, google-visualization, linechart

Is there a way to add a point with custom coordinates to a line chart using Google Charts like this http://prntscr.com/bt87cu ?

Source: http://paste2.org/8kcENGL6

Comment: Paste your code in the question, not with a link please.

Comment: possible using a `ComboChart` -- [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38016496/5090771)

Comment: Hi, you can use the exactly location custom point using the API: 
  [1]: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/points