# How to plot indicator circle onto google charts line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[Google charts' line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)

So, at the moment, I'm just getting used to google charts. But in future, I'm looking to plot a function. Once that line is drawn, I'd like to add a dynamic indicator circle that will travel along the path of the line as I adjust the values that plotted the line.

So to summarise:

- Plot a permanent line from a function*
- Have a circle that travels the path of the line as I adjust the values of the function. *(main question)*

New to google charts and not sure how easily you can do something like this.

To maybe clarify: I will be using a slider to control a value, as I move the slider the line will not change, but an "indicator" circle will change position to fit the new values; i.e. plotting a circle dynamically as the value changes.

Not sure if it helps, but my current graph looks simply like this:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

drawChart();

function drawChart() {
 
 
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['somVar1', 'someVar2'],
  ['0.001'  ,   0.02],
  ['0.003'  ,   0.07],
  ['0.01'   ,   0.2],
  ['0.03'   ,   0.6 ],
  ['0.1'    ,   1.8],
  ['0.3'    ,   4.8],
  ['1'      ,   10],
  ['3'      ,   15.2 ],
  ['10'     ,   18.2 ],
  ['30'     ,   19.4],
  ['100'    ,   19.8],
  ['300'    ,   19.93],
  ['1000'   ,   19.98],

 ]);

 //Graph styling and legend
 var options = {
  title: 'sumVar2 (%)',
  curveType: 'function',
  legend: { position: 'bottom' },
  vAxis: { title: 'someVar2 %'},
  hAxis: { title: 'someVar1'}
 };


 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lineGraph'));

 chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<div id="lineGraph" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
```

**(unfortunately with google charts, it looks like I have to do this by finding the range of values and spitting them out into an array - rather than being able to plot straight from a mathematical function)*

Comment: you can style the points of the line for the circles -- [have a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38016496/5090771) -- which uses stars...

Comment: @WhiteHat, that's note quite what I'm looking for. I have updated my question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) can be used to provide a function as the value for a series

use the [`setColumns`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns) method to set the function

you can pass a column index for an existing DataTable column or
a custom object with the calculation function

here, a DataView is created from a DataTable,
it uses the first column from the DataTable,
the next column is a function

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
dataView.setColumns([0, {
  calc: function (data, row) {
    return (2 * data.getValue(row, 0)) + 7;
  },
  type: 'number',
  label: 'Y1'
}]);
```

you can set multiple column functions,
but you cannot use the values from one function in another,
in the same DataView
to get around, reference the previous DataView in the current function

otherwise, you would have to dump the values to a new table,
then use the new table in another view to set the next function

you can modify the `series` options to create points rather than a line, i.e.

```
series: {
  1: {
    lineWidth: 0,
    pointSize: 8
  }
}
```

the following working snippet demonstrates how to save a reference to the first function, and use it later, such as when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    // DataTable X only
    var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['X'],
      [0.001],
      [0.003],
      [0.01],
      [0.03],
      [0.1],
      [0.3],
      [1],
      [3],
      [10],
      [30],
      [100],
      [300],
      [1000],
    ]);

    // use DataView to provide function for Y
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);

    // y1=2x+7
    var yCol1 = {
      calc: function (data, row) {
        return (2 * data.getValue(row, 0)) + 7;
      },
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Y1'
    };

    // use above object as Y1
    dataView.setColumns([0, yCol1]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    // draw Y2 when chart finishes drawing
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

      // add Y2 column
      dataView.setColumns([0, yCol1, {
        // y2=y1+(2x-1)
        calc: function (data, row) {
          //use reference to previous dataView
          return dataView.getValue(row, 1) + ((2 * data.getValue(row, 0)) - 1);
        },
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Y2'
      }]);

      chart.draw(dataView, {
        series: {
          1: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            pointSize: 8
          }
        }
      });
    });

    chart.draw(dataView);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

the same concept can be used to avoid having an array for the X values as well

just need to set an initial number of rows on a DataTable

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    // create blank table for the view
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('number', 'X');
    dataTable.addRows(20);

    // use DataView to provide function for X
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable);
    var xCol = {
      calc: function (data, row) {
        return (row + 1) * 0.3;
      },
      type: 'number',
      label: 'X'
    };
    dataView.setColumns([xCol]);

    // function for Y --> y1=2x+7
    var yCol1 = {
      calc: function (data, row) {
        return (2 * dataView.getValue(row, 0)) + 7;
      },
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Y1'
    };
    dataView.setColumns([xCol, yCol1]);

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

    // draw Y2 when chart finishes drawing
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {

      // add Y2 column
      dataView.setColumns([xCol, yCol1, {
        // y2=y1+(2x-1)
        calc: function (data, row) {
          //use reference to previous dataView
          return dataView.getValue(row, 1) + ((2 * data.getValue(row, 0)) - 1);
        },
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Y2'
      }]);

      chart.draw(dataView, {
        series: {
          1: {
            lineWidth: 0,
            pointSize: 8
          }
        }
      });
    });

    chart.draw(dataView);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39553121/5090771) if you're thinking of using a custom image as the indicator...