# Can I color segments of Google Charts Line Chart rather than coloring points?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

[image]

As you can see, the 1st point is colored green because it is below the desired range and the 2nd point is colored red because it is above the desired. A line segment takes the color of the succeeding point. However, I'd like the line segment to be split up with colors as well. (I'd also like to make it a gradient, but I'm sure I can figure that out once I can split up the line's colors how I like.)

Is this goal possible?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154287/5090771), not quite the same requirement but could be easily modified -- in the DataView, instead of comparing the row values to one another, compare against the _desired_ threshold...

Comment: Haven't got around to trying it yet. Will look into shortly.

Comment: Looks simpler than I expected

Comment: I implemented that method but I still have the same issue that the various line segments are colored in full rather than being split.

Comment: See how the line is red from point 1 to point 2? I would like the line to be green when below the dotted lines, yellow between, and red above. There are only 2 data points though.