# Multi-colored line chart with google visualization

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using google line chart in my project and facing a problem that I need to change color for some segments to visualize the target status changes over time. It should look like this:
[image]

I've searched around for quite long but couldn't find a way to do that with google chart.
My workaround is to add another series to the chart and alternately set the value of the second line eq to the first line based on the status but it looks tedious.
[image]

Is there a proper way to do this?  Here is a sample of my workaround solution:

```js
function drawMultipleTrendlineChart() {

  var chart;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales value A');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Sales value B');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2013, 3, 11), 200, 0],
    [new Date(2013, 4, 02), 500, 0],
    [new Date(2013, 5, 03), 700, 0],
    [new Date(2013, 6, 04), 800, 800],
    [new Date(2013, 7, 05), 500, 500],
    [new Date(2013, 8, 06), 900, 0],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 07), 800, 0],
    [new Date(2014, 1, 08), 1100, 1100],
    [new Date(2014, 2, 09), 1000, 1000],
    [new Date(2014, 2, 10), 1000, 0],
    [new Date(2014, 3, 11), 800, 0],
  ]);


  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    fractionDigits: 2,
    prefix: 'R$:'
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);
  var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
  });
  dateFormatter.format(data, 0);
  var chartHeight = 400;
  var chartWidth = 600;
  var chartOptions = {
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
    },
    title: 'Trendlines with multiple lines',
    isStacked: true,
    width: chartWidth,
    height: chartHeight,
    colors: ['#0000D8', '#00dddd'],
    hAxis: {
      title: 'example title',
      slantedText: false,
      slantedTextAngle: 45,
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
      format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'
    },
    chartArea: {
      left: 50,
      top: 20,
      width: (chartWidth - 10),
      height: (chartHeight - 90)
    }
  };
  chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('multipleTrendChart'));
  chart.draw(data, chartOptions);
}

google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawMultipleTrendlineChart
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="multipleTrendChart"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Adriano I've written from the beginning that I'm using google chart.

Comment: check this answer --> [How to change color for negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40138269/5090771)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at this answer [How to change color for negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40138269/5090771),  I tried and this works for me. The answer is using DataView API to manipulate the data.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawLineColors,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawLineColors() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Blue Team');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Red Team');

  data.addRows([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [3, 1700, 1600],
    [6, 1800, 1700],
    [9, 2500, 2423],
    [12, 3000, 2500],
    [15, 4700, 5800],
    [18, 5200, 5900],
    [21, 5500, 6000],
    [24, 6000, 6200],
    [27, 6800, 6700],
    [30, 7500, 7000],
    [33, 7800, 8200],
    [36, 7900, 9756],
    [39, 8000, 10752],
    [42, 9000, 13753],
    [45, 15000, 17845]
  ]);

  var options = {
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    enableInteractivity: false,
    width: 712,
    height: 156,
    backgroundColor: {
      fill: 'transparent'
    },
    curveType: 'function',
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Team Gold'
    }
  };

  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  dataView.setColumns([
    // reference first column by index
    0,
    // variance
    {
      calc: function(data, row) {
        return data.getValue(row, 1);
      },
      type: 'number',
      label: 'Y'
    },
    // variance color
    {
      calc: function(data, row) {
        var val = data.getValue(row, 2) - data.getValue(row, 1);
        if (val >= 0) {
          return '#0000FF';
        }
        return '#FF0000';
      },
      type: 'string',
      role: 'style'
    }
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(dataView, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```