# Google chart: how to change color for negative values in Annotation Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I currently have a nice AnnotationChart using GoogleCharts, But I want to change the color of the graph for negative values.

I got the solution for AreaChart/LineChart from this link:
[Google Chart : How to change color for negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137715/google-chart-how-to-change-color-for-negative-values)

But If I am applying the same for Annotation Chart I am getting the graph like this:[Annotation Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7heWl.jpg)
And I want a graph like this but in annotation chart:[Expected chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxbzm.jpg)

Can anyone give the solution for this?

After using provided solution, I am getting the chart like this:[image: Chart with provided solution]

All I want is a chart with zoom options like AnnotationChart. Do you have any other way to do this? 
I tried to do this with AreaChart. So I am able to add scroll zoom in the bottom of the area chart but didn't find the way to add zoom buttons on top.
[image]

Comment: Please add the part you are having trouble in. Try to add the content here instead of using links. As the content may get removed in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for annotation charts, the only way to set custom colors,
is using the `colors` option

which means if you want two colors,
you'll need two series of data (two y-axis data table columns)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['annotationchart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Positive');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Negative');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2018, 3, 20), 10, null],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 21), 5, null],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 23), null, -5],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 24), null, -10],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 25), null, -5],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 27), 10, null],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 28), 5, null],
    [new Date(2018, 3, 29), 0, 0]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  var options = {
    colors: ['#2196f3', '#f44336'],
    fill: 25,
    height: 400
  };
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. But I don't have [date, 0, 0] data in my CSV file. So the chart is not looking continuous like Area Chart. I can't change the data file with [date, 0, 0]. Can you suggest any solution for that?