# Combine google Bell curve chart and Bar chart in one

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have created Bell Curve chart using Google charts but now problem is, i have to combine Bar chart and Bell Curve chart like below image or you can check [this link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-normal-distribution.html)

[image]

Bell curve chart code:-

```js
  function drawChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('number', 'X Value');

            data.addColumn('number', 'Y Value');

            function NormalDensityZx(x, Mean, StdDev) {

                var a = x - Mean;

                return Math.exp(-(a * a) / (2 * StdDev * StdDev)) / (Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * StdDev);

            }

            var chartData = new Array([]);

            var index = 0;

            for (var i = -20; i < 50; i += 1) {

                chartData[index] = new Array(2);

                chartData[index][0] = i;

                chartData[index][1] = NormalDensityZx(i, 20, 10);
              
                index++;

            }
            
            data.addRows(chartData);

            //options = { height: 500, width: 800, legend: 'none' };

            //options.hAxis = {};

            //options.hAxis.minorGridlines = {};

            //options.hAxis.minorGridlines.count = 12;

            var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, {
                height: 700, width: 1200, legend: 'none', annotation: {
                    // index here is the index of the DataTable column providing the annotation
                    1: {
                        style: 'line'
                    }
                } });

        }

        google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>http://exceluser.com/downloads/examples/post_900_102/index.htmlt</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="chart">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) allows combining series of different types

in the options, provide the `seriesType` for the default type
then use the `series` option to assign different types to specific series
e.g.

```
    seriesType: 'area',
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'bars'
      }
    }
```

series `0` will be the first y-axis column in the data table

see following working snippet...

a bar is added for every fifth data point

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawChart,
    packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'X Value');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Y Value');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Columns');

    function NormalDensityZx(x, Mean, StdDev) {
        var a = x - Mean;
        return Math.exp(-(a * a) / (2 * StdDev * StdDev)) / (Math.sqrt(2 * Math.PI) * StdDev);
    }

    var chartData = new Array([]);
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = -20; i < 50; i += 1) {
        chartData[index] = new Array(2);
        chartData[index][0] = i;
        chartData[index][1] = NormalDensityZx(i, 20, 10);

        // add bars
        if ((i % 5) === 0) {
          chartData[index][2] = NormalDensityZx(i, 20, 10);
        } else {
          chartData[index][2] = null;
        }

        index++;
    }

    data.addRows(chartData);
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 700,
        legend: 'none',
        seriesType: 'area',
        series: {
          1: {
            type: 'bars'
          }
        },
        width: 1200
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**

recommend **not** using `jsapi` to load google charts
it is an old version, and according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

Comment: fyi: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016496/5090771) for another example of a bell curve, in which shading is added for each standard deviation...

Comment: Thank you for replay, Accepted!!