# create filled linear chart with chartjs for specific datasets

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a linear chart like a curve for different datasets but with start and end range for the x and y.
I want the start and end point of each dataset start from x y, how can convert the y line as values but takes labels? I tried to do something similar on the codepen but still need more to be similar to the image.

```
var data = {
  labels: ["Group A", "Group B", "Group C", "Group D", "Group E"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Group A",
      backgroundColor: gradient,
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#911215",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 5, y: 5 }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Group B",
      backgroundColor: "green",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "green",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 5, y: 5 },
        { x: 10, y: 10 }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Group C",
      backgroundColor: gradient,
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#911215",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 10, y: 10 },
        { x: 60, y: 60 },
        { x: 60, y: 10 }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Group D",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "blue",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 60, y: 10 },
        { x: 0, y: 5 }
      ]
    },
    {
      label: "Group E",
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      pointBackgroundColor: "white",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "pink",
      data: [
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 10 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 },
        { x: 0, y: 0 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

[image]
[codepen](https://codepen.io/fayekramzy/pen/oNbdbNO)

Comment: What is the function of the curve? You will need to provide the values for that as well...

Comment: @WhiteHat Not sure what do you mean? But let's say on the y axis we have from 1 to 10 and group A starts from zero to 2, group B starts from 2 to 3 and so on ..

Comment: You'll have to provide the values to fill in the curve, else you'll just have a straight line from 0 - 2. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016496/5090771) using Google charts, the ranges are based on the standard deviations.

Comment: @WhiteHat Great sample! That what I wanted but what I've is just range from (0-5, 5-10, ..etc) So, I've to create my own function to draw the dots. I thought I can draw line from x1,y1 to x2,y2 or at least ([{x:0, y:0},{x:0, y:0},{x:10,y:0},{x:10,y:5}] and this will draw the first set (Group A).